# Batch script to find files which are 2 days older than the current date 

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp

I need to move the below files in the specified folder (`C:\temp\`). The files present in the temp folder are as below

```
systemfile.20100604.txt
systemfile.20100603.txt
systemfile.20100602.txt
systemfile.20100601.txt
systemfile.20100531.txt
systemfile.20100530.txt
```

Consider today as 20100604. So, I need to move all the files except `systemfile.20100604.txt` & `systemfile.20100603.txt` from `C:\temp` to `C:\Archive`.

How can we achieve this using batch script in Windows XP ?

Regards,
Orbit.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://web.mac.com/mjlucas62/iWeb/16475EB9-D054-43A3-A1AF-A633483D5ADE/E9FBE28B-D970-477E-9603-BC0F7749E49A/BEAFDF94-FBA8-4DFA-97EF-FCEA606CE613.html)

And remove the command 4 and the folder path and you will be able to achieve what you want

Comment: hi raghuram,
I need to do it without installing any other softwares. how can we do it?